# URI Formats not Supported: while downloading remote file from Web client in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, uri, webclient

I'm trying to download a file from the server . While passing a link to the download File , it is throwing an error

**URI Formats are not supported ** and pointing at "link "- string contains server file address

```
string link =
    http:\\www.nse-india.com\DERIVATIVES\2012\AUG\fo22AUG2012bhav.csv.zip

          WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        var ua = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
        wc.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
```

and downloading code goes like this

```
    try
  {
   wc.DownloadFile(@link, "H:\\ZipTest\\ZipText\\nt.zip"); // Here Showing error
  _status = true;
   fileCount++;

  } catch (Exception ex)

  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    _status = false;
    }
```

if i used the same address in the web browser it downloading properly or if a replace some other files then also i can download from the same code only for this particular file i am facing problem , any idea??

Comment: Are you really using backslashes instead of slashes in the `link` variable? Because if you are, that's probably your problem.

Comment: Sheesh, why not take a moment to fix all your typos and malformed code? And why not accept some more answers while you're at it?

Comment: Jonathan Wood, sorry i was in little hurry to get answer and will correct it . correct , its only url mistyping . i do accept answers most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url need little modification

Change

```
string link =
    "http:\www.nse-india.com\DERIVATIVES\2012\AUG\fo22AUG2012bhav.csv.zip"
```

To

```
string link =
    "http://www.nse-india.com/DERIVATIVES/2012/AUG/fo22AUG2012bhav.csv.zip"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your url is corrupted:  `http:\www.nse-indi.......`. It should be something like `http://www.nse-india.com/DERIVATIVES/2012/AUG/fo22AUG2012bhav.csv.zip`