# zip file Error URI formats are not supported

Tags: c#, zip, azure-blob-storage

Here I am trying to zip the contents of a directory using [dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) ,and I am getting this **error message** :*URI formats are not supported.*
Here is the code I use to do this .

```
string strDirectoryName="http://zyx.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/mymusic"
       using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddDirectory(strDirectoryName);
                zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                zip.Save("zipFileToCreate");
            }
```

I looked into the answer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323269/uri-formats-not-supported-while-downloading-remote-file-from-web-client-in-c-sh) .I am also following the same url format ,then why I am getting this error .Please help me resolve this error

I modified the above code as follows  ,and the zip files are getting created but are corrupted.
In my blob container 'myfiles' ,I want to create a zip file named "mymusic.zip" by reading all my files and folders within myMusic folder while retaining the same folder structure inside the zip file.The following code creates the zip file, but the zip file is getting corrupted .Any suggestions to resolve this ?

```
string ofurl = @"http://myxyzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/mymusic";
            string ofBlob = @"http://myxyz.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles";
          dBlob = new CloudBlob(blobClient.GetBlobReference(ofBlob));

            using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = dBlob.DownloadByteArray();
                using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                {
                    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    zipFile.AddEntry(ofurl+".zip", fileBytes);
                }
                var sas = offlineContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
                {
                    Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write,
                 // SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(this.timeOutSeconds)
                });

                using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zipFile.Save(zipStream);
                    zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var blobRef = ofContainer.GetBlobReference(ofurl);
                    blobRef.UploadFromStream(zipStream);
                }

            }
```

**here with my code above ,why my zip file are getting corrupted?**

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/discussions/250867) looks like addresses both the issue and solution.

Cheeso - `DotNetZip can read from filesystems.  It cannot read from http sources.  An easy way to do what you want is to send a GET request to the HTTP resource, and then pass the ResponseStream to the call to AddFile().`

He then goes on to code out a sample solution

Comment: The example provided uses  the ZipFile.AddEntry() method that accepts a stream ,but in my case ,I need to zip a particular directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with dotnetzip, but I think I know your problem.

When accessing items to the server use the server path, not the URI (web address).  The operating system doesn't know that `http://your.website` is actually part of its `c:\\web\website\somedirectory`